# code segment of kernel thread

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

Is there any way to get address and size of code segment of linux kernel thread (like `task_struct->mm->mmap->vm_start` and `vm_end` for active task with  `task_struct->mm != 0`)?

Comment: You want it for the idle thread? Not for your current task?

Comment: I need it for all kernel threads

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you go through the taskstats interface from the Linux kernel which can provide info on all the Linux threads, including VM stats.

Have a look on the [doc](http://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/accounting/taskstats.txt), as well as on the [header](http://www.cs.fsu.edu/~baker/devices/lxr/http/source/linux/include/linux/taskstats.h) for the interface.

There is no easy way to hack into the kernel to enumerate all the `task_struct` available.

Comment: As I understand, this interface with `struct taskstats` provides information like in `/proc/<PID>/sched` - it doesn't help me

Comment: Then, I don't get what you want. This interface allows you querying info per pid, which corresponds according to the doc to a `task_struct`. Then, in the returned struct, you have `coremen` and `virtmem`. You indeed don't have beginning address, but I'm not sure you can get it otherwise.